# How to prove Euler's pentagonal theorem? Some hints will help

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, complex-analysis

Euler's pentagonal theorem is the following equation:
    $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-q^n)=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^m q^{\frac{3m^2-m}{2}}$
where $|q|<1$ is a complex number.
I hope that someone will me some hints on this.

Comment: have you looked at wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem

Comment: Er...You are right.I should have first looked it up in the WIKI.

Comment: See also Lecture 3 of [Fuchs-Tabacnikov. Mathematical Omnibus](http://www.math.psu.edu/tabachni/Books/taba.pdf)

Answer (score 12):

While there is a lot of value to the different bijective proofs known for Euler's pentagonal theorem, perhaps the proof that's easiest to see without having to draw pictures is Euler's original idea.

Define $A_N=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{N(n-1)}(1-q^N)\cdots (1-q^{N+n-1})$. Start with the identity
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)=1-a_1-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n(1-a_1)\cdots (1-a_{n-1})$$
and plug in $a_n=q^n$. This gives you $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)=1-q-q^2A_1$. Now to finish the proof of Euler's theorem you need to prove the following recursion
$$A_N=1-q^{2N+1}-q^{3N+2}A_{N+1}.$$
This identity is equivalent to proving
$$q^{2N+1}-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{N(n-1)}(1-q^{N+1})\cdots(1-q^{N+n-1})(1-q^N+q^{3N+n+1}-q^{4N+2n+1})=0$$
and it starts
$$(q^{2N+1}-1)+(1-q^N+q^{3N+2}-q^{4N+3})+q^N(1-q^{N+1})(1-q^N+q^{3N+3}-q^{4N+5})+\cdots$$
$$=q^N(1-q^{N+1})(q^{2N+2}-1)+q^N(1-q^{N+1})(1-q^N+q^{3N+3}-q^{4N+5})+\cdots$$
$$=q^{2N}(1-q^{N+1})(q^{2N+3}-1)+\cdots$$
and if you've noticed the pattern, filling out the details shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: Surely, it is a very nice idea.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a somewhat combinatoric proof. Note that for $k>0$, the coefficient of $q^k$ in
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)
$$
is the number of even, increasing partitions of $k$ minus the number of odd, increasing partitions of $k$.  Take $k=7$, for example. There are $3$ even, increasing partitions of $7$: $1+6$, $2+5$, and $3+4$; there are $2$ odd, increasing partitions of $7$: $7$ and $1+2+4$.  Thus, the coefficient of $q^7$ is $3-2=1$.

In what follows, we will only be concerned with increasing partitions. There is a nice way to cancel the even partitions with the odd partitions, but it fails in a few cases.  These failing cases are what give rise to the non-zero terms in the summation.

Here is the way to pair even and odd partitions. Suppose the smallest summand in a partition is $m$.

1. if the $m$ largest summands are consecutive, then remove $m$ and add $1$ to the $m$ largest summands.
2. if only the $j$ largest summands are consecutive $(j<m)$, then subtract $1$ from the $j$ largest summands and prepend $j$.

Note that (1) is the inverse of (2) and vice-versa.  Take $k=6$, for example. There are $4$ partitions, and they are paired as follows: $6\leftrightarrow 1+5$ and $1+2+3\leftrightarrow 2+4$.

Each of the two pairings above fail in exactly one way for each $m>0$,

1. for the partition $m+(m+1)+...+(2m-1)$ [$m$ terms totaling $(3m-1)m/2$]
   (this fails because $m$ is to be removed, yet it is also to be incremented)
2. for the partition $(m+1)+(m+2)+...+2m$ [$m$ terms totaling $(3m+1)m/2$]
   (this fails because $m$ is to be prepended, yet $m+1$ is also to be decremented)

Thus, after cancellation, we have leftover partitions contributing $(-1)^m q^{(3m-1)m/2}$ and $(-1)^m q^{(3m+1)m/2}$ for $m>0$.  Noting that $(3(-m)-1)(-m)/2=(3m+1)m/2$ and that the constant term of the product is $1=q^0$, we get
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^m q^{(3m-1)m/2}
$$

Comment: Surely,very elementary.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

There are two other proofs you might like: [Andrews's proof](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-02/S0002-9939-1965-0171725-X/home.html) of [Jacobi triple product identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product)  which implies Euler's Pentagonal Theorem, and has a direct bijective proof given by Sylvester (see [my survey](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/psurvey.pdf).

Another, quite different proof is due to Dyson and given [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980069800062) (see my survey and [this popular article](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/finefull.pdf) explaining the connection).