# closed form evaluation of $\int_{-1}^{1} (x;x)_{\infty}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This was mostly provoked by the graph on http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPochhammer.html which suggests
that the integral

$$\int_{-1}^1 (x;x)_\infty\,dx\approx 1.28830088867\ldots$$
is convergent. *Is it convergent to something tidy?*

I've used $x$ instead of $q$ here because $q$ is usually associated with being in the unit disc on the complex plane.

Seeing the fractional part start with $0.288$ is somewhat suggestive, given that $(1/2,1/2)_{\infty}=0.2887880950866024\ldots$ (entry 25 on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeSearching.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Result*

The result of the integral

$$i = \int_{-1}^1 (x;x)_\infty\,dx $$

where

$$(x;x) = \prod _{m=1}^{\infty } \left(1-x^m\right)\tag{1}$$

can be obtained in closed form as follows

$$i = s = s_1 + s_2$$

where

$$ s_1 =2 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{24 k^2+2 k+1} = -\frac{1}{23} i \left(\sqrt{23} \pi  \cot \left(\frac{1}{24} \left(\pi -i \sqrt{23} \pi \right)\right)-\sqrt{23} \pi  \cot \left(\frac{1}{24} \left(\pi +i \sqrt{23} \pi \right)\right)\right)\tag{2}$$

which can be simplified to

$$s_{1a} =\frac{2 \pi  \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)}{\sqrt{23} \left(\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)-\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)}\tag{2a}$$

and

$$s_2=2 \sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{-24 k^2+34 k-13} = -\frac{1}{23} i \left(\sqrt{23} \pi  \tan \left(\frac{1}{24} \left(5 \pi -i \sqrt{23} \pi \right)\right)-\sqrt{23} \pi  \tan \left(\frac{1}{24} \left(5 \pi +i \sqrt{23} \pi \right)\right)\right)\tag{3} $$

which can be simplified to

$$s_{2a} = -\frac{2 \pi  \sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)}{\sqrt{23} \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{23} \pi }{12}\right)\right)}\tag{3a}$$

Numerically,

$$N(s_1) = 2.2680458411340673629 ...$$ 
$$N(s_2) = -0.97974495246014613277...$$
$$N(s) = 1.28830088867392123018... $$

*Derivation*

Using Euler's theorem of pentagonal numbers [1] we can write the product as a sum

$$\prod _{m=1}^{\infty } \left(1-x^m\right)=\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty } (-1)^n x^{\frac{1}{2} n (3 n+1)}\tag{4}$$

The right hand side can be integrated term by term giving the result as one infinite sum. This in turn can be decomposed into two sums with indices $n = 4k$ and $n = 4k-3$.

Related material can be found in [2] and [3].

*References*

[1] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html

Further reading

[2] https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505373.pdf, L.Euler (1775), On the remarkable properties of the pentagonal numbers

[3] MSE: [How to prove Euler's pentagonal theorem? Some hints will help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55738/how-to-prove-eulers-pentagonal-theorem-some-hints-will-help/55744)

Comment: I'm going to accept this. But we're not done quite yet, I think. I think we want to translate those sinhs and coshs into values of the Dedekind eta function itself.

Comment: @deoxygerbe I would be interested in your own attempts to find a closed form of the integral.

Comment: basically what I have in mind is we have a lot of $\exp(\pi i \sqrt{23}/12)$ terms in the two expressions in the above: I propose that we view them as parts of a Dedekind eta function, and transform the expression appropriately.l